# Find a line integral along the parabola $y=4-x^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I'm trying to understand how to solve this integral, but unsuccessfully. Could you help me to get the answer $H$, or at least $Z$?

$$Z =  \int_L^{}(x-y) dx + x \, dy$$

$$\text{when:} ~~~ L: y = 4 - x^{2}, ~A(1;3), ~B(2;0);$$

$$H = \sqrt[5]{90876845839099} \cdot (Z+0,5) \cdot 3 + 1$$

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be more specific?

Comment: @AntanasVezdas: Welcome to MSE! Please make sure I transcribed the problem correctly. Also, can you please describe some of the notation (for example, is this using some Matlab notation for vectors)? Regards

Comment: I think this is a line integral, right? I'm guessing that H is the answer, A and B are the sarting and ending points of the curve L, although I don't know what the Z stands for.

Comment: What i have is just this equation, and what i need to get is H, yes. No more other information given.

Comment: @Amzoti: why did you typeset it as \large?

Comment: @tomasz: I have a junky monitor and the LaTex displays better that way. Is it offensive with your display? There is really no other reason as I cannot read it clearly. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti you can increase the zoom factor of the LaTeX by right clicking on it and going to "Math Settings".  For those of us who have already done this, using `\large` is overkill!

Comment: @AntonioVargas: thanks! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti sorry, I meant "Scale All Math..." instead of Zoom Factor.  It's been a while since I used it.  Hope it makes using the site easier for you :)

Answer (score 1):

We're trying to integrate the vector field $X(x,y)=(x-y,x)$ over the line $\gamma (t)=(t,4-t^2)$ with $t\in \left[ 1,2\right] $. We have:

$$
\int_\gamma X(r)dr =\int_1^2X(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma '(t)dt
$$
as per definition (the point "$\cdot$" stands for inner product of vectors). Substituting the expressions we already know,
$$
\int_\gamma X(r)dr =\int_1^2(t-4+t^2,t)\cdot(1,-2t)dt=\int_1^2t-4+t^2-2t^2=
$$
$$
=\int_1^2(-t^2+t-4)dt=\left(-\dfrac{t^3}{3}+\dfrac{t^2}{2}+t\right)\mid^2_1=-\dfrac{8}{3}+2+2+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{2}-1=
$$
$$
-\dfrac{7}{3}+\dfrac{5}{2}=\dfrac{1}{6}
$$

You check it tough; I'm very sleepy.

Comment: seems its wrong.the answer i need to get is 4.5 of Z

Comment: This doesn't make sense, what is Z?

Comment: Z is what i need to get. Its answer of integration. should be. here it is a hint i got: http://i.imgur.com/edHHsaN.png

Comment: I am having the impression that you are not very sure of what you are asking.

Comment: answer H = 9286